# SELECT - too many rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

let me show you a simple presentation on database structure:

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxPzs.png)

> Query's parameters:
>
> -id_category
>
> -id_language
>
> -id_account

I need to select all rows from wordconfigs table where id_wordconfig is diffrent from id_wordconfig stored in hiddenwords table.

For example wordconfigs table cointains:

> id_wordconfig = 1 (this row is related to successively: **id_account=1
>   (imporatant that 1)**, id_language=1, id_category=1)
>
> id_wordconfig = 2 (this row is related to successively: **id_account=1
>   (imporatant that 1)**, id_language=1, id_category=1)

I pass parameters to query:

> -id_category = 1
>
> -id_language = 1
>
> **-id_account = 2 (other than assigned to wordconfigs in example)**

**Example 1**

hiddenwords table is empty -> query returns wordconfid with id 1 and 2

**Example 2**

hiddenwords table contains:

> id_hiddenwords = 1; id_wordconfig=1; **id_account=1**

query returns also wordconfig with id 1 and 2 (because id_account is diffrent from passed to query)

**Example 3**

hiddenwords table contains:

> id_hiddenwords = 1; id_wordconfig=1; **id_account=2**

query returns just wordconfig with id 2 (because hiddenwords contains id_wordconfig=1 and id_account=2 like passed to query)

**Example 4**

hiddenwords table contains:

> id_hiddenwords = 1; id_wordconfig=1; **id_account=2**
>
> id_hiddenwords = 1; id_wordconfig=2; **id_account=1 (different that passed to query)**

query returns just wordconfig with id = 2

**Example 5**

hiddenwords table contains:

> id_hiddenwords = 1; id_wordconfig=1; **id_account=2**
>
> id_hiddenwords = 1; id_wordconfig=2; **id_account=2**

query should nothing returns

I've created a simple query for this task:

```
SELECT wc.*
FROM categorywordconfig cwc, categories c, languages l, accounts a, wordconfigs wc
LEFT JOIN hiddenwords hw ON hw.id_wordconfig<>wc.id_wordconfig
WHERE wc.id_wordconfig=cwc.id_wordconfig
AND cwc.id_category=c.id_category
AND c.id_language=l.id_language
AND l.id_account=a.id_account
AND c.id_category=1
AND l.id_language=1
AND hw.id_account=2
```

The given query works for examples from 1 to 4. The Example 5 should nothing returns but with this query it's return all rows (so wordconfig with id 1 and 2) Why is that? What's wrong with it?

Edit:
I've just simple changed query to:

```
SELECT wc.* FROM categorywordconfig cwc, categories c, languages l, accounts a, wordconfigs wc
WHERE wc.id_wordconfig=cwc.id_wordconfig
AND cwc.id_category=c.id_category AND c.id_language=l.id_language
AND l.id_account=a.id_account AND c.id_category=1 AND l.id_language=1 
AND wc.id_wordconfig NOT IN (SELECT id_wordconfig FROM hiddenwords WHERE id_account=2)
```

And it's working :)

Comment: Sample data as text tables and a db<>fiddle would help your explanation.

Comment: I did not understand why only `hiddenwords` is joined with proper explicit join syntax and rest are joined with old coma syntax. That might be a reason for the wrong output. Please convert your query to join syntax. Start with 2 tables and then include other tables one after one. Hopefully you will get expected result.

Comment: Please present sample data in [table format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852). Your choice of using a "list" is extremely hard to follow